# Unable to add EPEL repo using Ansible - RHEL 7

Tags: ansible, yum

I am trying to install the EPEL repo on `Ansible` using a playbook.

The `play` I have is as follows:

```
- name: add epel repo   
  tags: addEpelRepo
          yum: name=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm state=present
          register: epelRepoOut
          notify:
            - yum update
        - debug: var=epelRepoOut.stdout_lines
```

Even after executing this play, EPEL is not installed. Running `yum repolist` does not contain EPEL.
My question(s):
1. How do I enable the EPEL repo?
2. I have also tried `yum_repository` module in the following play:

```
- name: Add repository
  yum_repository:
    name: epel
    description: EPEL YUM repo
    baseurl: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/
```

While an EPEL repo file gets created in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, I am unable to install anything from this file. How do I get this right?

UPDATE:  Output is:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "conf_file": null,
            "disable_gpg_check": true,
            "disablerepo": null,
            "enablerepo": null,
            "exclude": null,
            "install_repoquery": true,
            "list": null,
            "name": [
                "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm"
            ],
            "state": "present",
            "update_cache": false,
            "validate_certs": true
        },
        "module_name": "yum"
    },
    "msg": "",
    "rc": 0,
    "results": []
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Are there any debug messages on the `epelRepoOut` ?

Comment: You may try `disable_gpg_check=yes` option.

Comment: @Kadir: Thank you for replying. I have updated the question with the output..

Comment: from the output it seems like epel-release rpm is installed. Can you post the content of the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` file?

Comment: There is no epel.repo file in that folder..

Comment: When you say that the 'yum repolist' does not show the EPEL and you are unable to install anything, "when" are you seeing that (in the next play, or even after the playbook completes)?  If you run this play then manually login and run 'yum update' then 'yum repolist', does that show EPEL?

Comment: @dan_linder: i cannot install anything in the epel repo. either within plays or from the command line. `yum install clamav` does nothing for instance.

Comment: Have you already tried to do a yum update in between to update the yum cache after using yum_repository?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this two ways IIRC. (1) I've installed an rpm that is in my repository (epel-release). (2) I template out the yum.repos.d file myself. 
If you choose the second method, you might have to either disable gpg checking or use the rpm command to import the key.